# Examples of hacking causing serious destruction or death

Tags: attacks

We are fast approaching a world where self-driving cars are both a reality and common. See for example [Uber's self-driving car pilot program in Pittsburgh](https://techcrunch.com/2016/09/14/1386711/) and [Google's continual self-driving car development](https://www.google.com/selfdrivingcar/).

As with any computerized system, self-driving cars are susceptible to hacking (and many cases of car hacking exist already). I forsee this continuing to remain a problem long after self-driving cars are common-place.

Now, it seems to me that once self-driving cars are common-place, the need for each car to completely drive itself might become unnecessary, and instead a natural development might be that cars communicate with a master computer(s) which guides all cars on the road (while the car itself handles the simple tasks like lane-shifts and distance maintenance). The benefit of course being that you get to command a fleet of cars as a system and they can all respond to problems/accidents in tandem and traffic can be controlled by a computer with more knowledge than a single car. Whether or not such a system is likely to develop is *not* the subject of this question, I merely provide it as an example for my question below.

If such a system were to be hacked, it could allow the hacker to cause untold wanton destruction and death (even more so than hacking a single self-driving car). It is this fear which I believe will be a major contribution to the push-back against self-driving cars (and any system which develops surrounding it, such as the one I described above). **What I'm interested in are examples of computers or systems that exist today that are feasibly hackable and would allow the hacker to cause a similar or higher level of physical destruction and/or death as in the centralized self-driving computer example I gave above.** Most hacking involves stealing money or personal information, but I want an example I can point to and say: Why are you so worried about this future technology when you have a parallel technology that exists today and hasn't been exploited as you fear this new technology might? Any expansion on *how* hackable your example system is (e.g., what would be required to hack it and how hard it would be) would be welcome.

Comment: It's likely we'll have self-driving cars working in a hybrid system from the very beginning. Consider human drivers: many are taking directions from the map app servers. It seems reasonable self-driving cars would do the same.

Comment: zephyr - this is currently way too broad, as any computer that controls aeroplanes, trains, boats, submarines, hospital equipment, power stations etc etc etc could be hacked and cause deaths.

Comment: there are no unhackable computers.

Comment: Maybe you want to refocus on known examples, as per thel3l's answer?

Comment: @RoryAlsop Then perhaps a better question might be, why aren't these systems being hacked currently (to cause large destruction and death).

Comment: no - that wouldn't be a better question. It would be entirely off topic. "why" is almost never on topic

Comment: There have been some case of ransomware against hospital.

Answer (score 1):

All from DEFCON from the past:

[Cesar Cerrudo on hacking traffic lights](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_j9lELCSZQw)

Barnaby Jack also had a talk scheduled on hacking pacemakers, but he died before he ever spoke IIRC.

Comment: I had a section on car hacking, but removed it as OP said he didn't want to see car hacking as an example.